# JqGrid: have a dropped row stay where it was dropped

Tags: jqgrid, drag-and-drop

I am playing with JQGrid and its drag ad drop.

There are good examples here:

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

I want to drag a row and dropped it in the same grid. Here is how I achieved this:

```
jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#grid1'});
```

The problem is that in the above setting, a dropped row is always placed in the top of the grid (the first row). I want to a dropped row stay where it was dropped. How can I do this? If a jsfiddle is needed, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `sortableRows` method instead of `gridDnD` to reorder rows in the grid.

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked like a charm. I thought there must be an easy config. Thanks, again!